# How do I access values in a Perl Hash of Array of Arrays?

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array, reference

I have built a hash containing arrays of arrays, let's call it %hash_multidim, such that the output from Data::Dumper looks like so:

```
      'Key1' => [
                   [
                     '-3.81',
                     '-1.91',
                     '-1.86',
                     '-1.70'
                   ],
                   [
                     '1.35',
                     '1.04',
                     '-1.01',
                     '-2.69'
                   ]
                 ],
      'Key2' => [
                    [
                      '-1.63'
                    ],
                    [
                      '-1.17'
                    ]
                  ],
```

Now, I would like to access and perform manipulations on the bottom-most level in this structure.  For example, for 'Key1' I want to find the mean of the in row 1 (aka the mean of the array at [0]).
Using List::Util qw(sum), I have written a subroutine called mean:

```
sub mean {
    return sum(@_)/scalar(@_);
}
```

However, if using the subroutine, eg:

```
my $test = mean($hash_multidim{Key1}[0]);
print $test;
```

I do not get what I expect.  In fact, I get:

```
43678288
```

Where did I go wrong?  If I try to evaluate the result of

```
$hash_multidim{Key1}[0]
```

everything looks kosher.  E.g.,

```
@test2 = $hash_multidim{Key1}[0];
print Dumper(\@test2);
```

produces this output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '-3.81',
            '-1.91',
            '-1.86',
            '-1.70'
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$hash_multidim{Key1}[0]` is an array *reference*, but `mean` expects a list. So you just need to "dereference" it. The syntax is a little tricky, but it is

```
my $test = mean( @{$hash_multidim{Key1}[0]} );
```

Comment: Thanks!  My intuition was that it was a problem of dereferencing, but I messed up the syntax when attempting to fix it.  I tend to panic when dereferencing part of a multidimensional data structure.  Any tips (other than experience) or heuristics for knowing how/when to dereference?  Actually, I'm fairly sure I already know when, but the how (for complex situations) often leaves me befuddled even after reading through perldocs.

Comment: If your expression starts with `$`, then you always have a scalar (which could be a reference to an array or hash). If it starts with `@` or `%`, then it's an array or hash.

Answer (score 3):

`$hash_multidim{Key1}[0]` is a scalar whose value is a reference to an array. You're passing that single scalar to `mean` when you mean to pass the values of the elements of the referenced array.

```
my $test = mean( @{ $hash_multidim{Key1}[0] } );
```

---

Note: The division operator cannot divide by a list, only by a number. As such, it imposes a scalar context on its operands. Your use of `scalar` is superfluous. You could simply use

```
sub mean { sum(@_)/@_ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: division by lists!  I thought that I could write it your way, but I don't always program in Perl and I like to be explicit for myself (so I don't panic when I go back to my code later).